# how do i get 'latitude' and 'longitude 'and show it to your map

Tags: javascript, php, sql, wordpress, meta-boxes

I just started to learn about google map api and apply it to wordpress. From the document https://docs.metabox.io/fields/map/, I got the address from the map 'Array ([0] => 16.06765920497858,108.2019980633545,14)'. So how do I get 'lat' and 'long', and show that location to my map.
below is my whole code:

```
function location_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
  $prefix = 'tuyen_custom_';
  $meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'personal',
    'title'      => 'Option Google Maps',
    'post_types' => 'dia-diem',
    'context'    => 'normal',
    'priority'   => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
      array(
        'name'  => 'Link',
        'desc'  => 'Nhập link được liên kết',
        'id'    => $prefix . 'link',
        'type'  => 'text',
      ),
        array(
            'id'   => 'address',
            'name' => 'Địa chỉ',
            'desc'  => 'Nhập vào địa chỉ',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'id'            => $prefix . 'map',
            'name'          => 'Vị trí bản đồ',
            'type'          => 'map',
            'address_field'          => 'map',
            'std'           => '16.058339, 108.220280',
            'address_field' => 'address',
            'api_key'       => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        ),
    )
  );
  return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'location_register_meta_boxes' );
```

Export to the address:

```
$address[] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'tuyen_custom_map',true);
print_r($address);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the `$address` var as a string if we only have one value to worry about. It looks like we use the `std` key for the default location. Give the code below a shot.

```
function location_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {

  // Get the latitude, longitude.
  $address = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tuyen_custom_map', true ); 

  $prefix = 'tuyen_custom_';
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'personal',
    'title' => 'Option Google Maps',
    'post_types' => 'dia-diem',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'Link',
        'desc' => 'Nhập link được liên kết',
        'id' => $prefix . 'link',
        'type' => 'text',
      ),
      array(
        'id' => 'address',
        'name' => 'Địa chỉ',
        'desc' => 'Nhập vào địa chỉ',
        'type' => 'text',
      ),
      array(
        'id' => $prefix . 'map',
        'name' => 'Vị trí bản đồ',
        'type' => 'map',
        'address_field' => 'map',
        'std' => $address,
        'address_field' => 'address',
        'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      ),
    )
  );

  return $meta_boxes;

}

add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'location_register_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I will note that. But I just want to get the 'latitude' 'longitude' values ​​on tuyen_custom_map to bring it to my map.
" <script>
 function initMap() {
     var myLatLng = {lat: 16.0566682, lng: 108.1733446}; ......... "